# how to read positional parameters of a command from a file

Tags: bash, io-redirection

> Q1.i want to read positional parameters of a command from file. 
>       means 
>       some_command positional params...
>       how do i do that?
>
> ```
> Q2. what is this line means :
>     echo $(0<file_name)
>    i can echo contents of file name using this command but when
>    i do echo 0<file_name it does nothing kindly clear my doubt.
> ```

Comment: How complicated a set of command line arguments do you need read from the file?  If you won't have quoted strings, or arguments with spaces, or backslashes, or variables to expand, or commands to execute with `$(...)`, etc, then it is relatively easy.  As you add more twists to the command line interpretation that is required, it grows harder.

Comment: This should be posted as two separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the positional parameters in with:

```
set -- $(<file_name)
```

... where `$(<xyz)` and `$(0<xyz)` are equivalent bashisms to:

```
set -- `cat xyz`
```

Comment: The `$(<xyz)` notation differs from `$(cat xyz)` in not actually creating a sub-process to read the file.  The net result is the same, but because there is one less process, the result should be obtained quicker.  The use of the `0` is tantamount to obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

A1) Use [`getopts` as suggested by the BashFAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035)

A2) `$()` executes a command. Same as "``"

Answer (score 0):

**A1:** In your script place this to set your positional parameters based on the contents of the file:

```
read -rd '' -a R < filename  ## Reads input from file, and splits it with the values from IFS ($' \t\n'). This doesn't only read a line. With no delimeter (-d ''), it reads the whole input.
set -- "${R[@]}"  ## "${R[@]}" will expand to multiple arguments depending on the values of the array R. This is just the common way to transfer the contents of an array to the positional parameters.
```

With formats like `$()` and `$(<file_input)`, the expanded value is also subject to word splitting, but could be changed due to pathname expansion. To prevent pathname expansion, either disable it with `noglob` (`set -o noglob`, `set -f`), or just use `read -a`.

**A2:** According to bash manual: *The command substitution $(cat file) can be replaced by the equivalent but faster $(< file).*. The optional number in front of it e.g. 0 which seem to be a custom input file descriptor doesn't actually seem to make a difference: `echo "$(<file)"` and `echo "$(40<file)"` is just the same.

***but when i do `echo 0<file_name` it does nothing***

It won't since that's already a form of redirection of input from `file_name`. And `echo` only sends output based on its parameters or arguments `echo arg1 arg2 ...`, not on input like cat: `cat < file_name`.

**Notes:**

- It's recommended that you only use a single argument for `echo`, and concatenate your strings inside doublequotes `""`.
- `0<` also is just the same as `<` for the default input uses fd 0.

Comment: thnx for reasponding but i have read that 0<file means redirecting the descripter to file. so when i do this $(0<file) then how its  read contents i am not executing any other command then why it is replacing it with $(cat 0<file) can u explain this to me that how $(<file) is equivalent to $(cat <file)

Comment: Just don't think that `$(<)` and `$()` are the same. They're both different syntaxes. `$(<file)` expands to contents of file as if it's done with `$(cat file)`. `cat` also sends input to output if it doesn't have an argument so `cat file` is just the same as `cat < file`, and so is `$(cat file)` being the same as `$(cat < file)`. See `cat --help`: *With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.*